# How to show a field in a view taken as input in a different content type?

Tags: views, nodes, entities

I made a form Company Information, which contains standard fields like Name, Address, Rating etc.

Now I am taking Rating from a different content type "Company Reviews", under Rating Field.

What I want to display various fields from Company Information and Company Reviews in a single view. I tried using the machine name in twig but somehow the view is showing values from Company Information but not from Company Reviews.

Does this sound familiar? I am sure it can be done but I am missing out something. Any help or even a direction is much appreciated, thanks.

---

[ UPDATE 1]

So, I was researching this for a while and just after posting the question I stumbled upon "Entity Reference", but it seems that this is not available for drupal 8
can we do this in drupal 8 somehow 
https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/entity-reference-views/

---

[ UPDATE 2]
The entity reference was suppose to show up in Add Relation under Advance Tab

[image: Add entity reference via advance tab]

And I am getting a few fields,  but not the ones I want.
neither the view is showing following entity relation 
[image]

instead, I am having this on my dashboard, 
[image]

so I went ahead and added Review content filter anyway, as a result, the Listing View started showing the reviews as companies, which was not the desired result, using review title as company title.

[image]

Do I require a module or should something have be-be done at content types Company Profile and Review?

[ UPDATE 3 ] The Answer is correct, Here is how did it, if anyone is interested.

It was rather simple,

Suppose you have Content-Type A, and Content-Type B, and a result View C

In Content Type A, you add a field, that is actually a Reference to Content-Type B, let's call it ref-AB. Similarly, Add add a field, that is actually a Reference to Content-Type A, say ref_BA. 
Now fields of A & B Content-Type are related, and you can show them in the view.

To Show them in a view, you need to add "reference to the content" as a relation in view ( Go to view> your-view > advance > add relation). Suppose, you added ref_BA to your view, then all fields of content type B, will be available in your view.

In your view, add the field you want to show, making relation to ref_BA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entity Reference is now included in Drupal 8 core.
To use it, simply add a field "Reference-Content" and you may use your Company Reviews content type. Then, following the tutorial from your link, you should be able to add any field from Company Reviews in a view showing content of type Company Information.
[image]

Comment: I want to use the said field in a View,

Comment: That's what I understood, yes. So now with your entity reference field, you may add a relationship based on this field in your View. Then, you add a field (let's simply say the title) and you choose the relationship previously built. Finally, you will display the title of the content referenced (here the Company Reviews). This works for any field or property.

Comment: Is there any tutorial for this ?

Comment: the one you mentioned is clear (OSTraining)

Comment: but my drupal setup is not showing "Entity Reference: Referenced Entity".